# Created new MSDE Instance, but can't connect to it

Tags: sql-server, msde

Hello all I have just created a new MSDE Instance. I started the instance in services.msc however when trying to set up a connection from "Data Sources (ODBC)> System DSN" It tells me that my credentials are invalid or the instance does not exist. It does exist. What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Do you mean desktop engine? That is a very old version. Are you sure it's not Microsoft express? Are you certain the server name is correct? What server name are you using?

Comment: you should add the connection string